# Nginx configuration not working

Tags: nginx

I've just switched from Apache to nginx and it still takes some getting used to (and a lot of learning).

I'm running a Pagekit website which has this configuration: https://gist.github.com/DarrylDias/be8955970f4b37fdd682

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.private.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    ssl_client_certificate  /etc/ssl/private/cloudflare.origin-pull-ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client       on;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    root /home/vhosts/domains/mydomain.com/public/;

    index index.php;

    # Leverage browser caching of media files for 30 days
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ttf|woff)\$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, mustrevalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Deny access to sensitive folders
    location ~* /(app|packages|storage|tmp)/.*$ { 
        return 403; 
    }

    # Deny access to files with the following extensions
    location ~* \.(db|json|lock|dist|md)$ { 
        return 403;
    }

    # Deny access to following files 
    location ~ /(config.php|pagekit|composer.lock|composer.json|LICENSE|\.htaccess) { 
        return 403; 
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_MOD_REWRITE  On;
    }
}
```

Unforunately, many (including me) have the issue that files with extensions such as `js|css|jpg|<etc>` are getting a `403` response because they're located inside either the `app or packages` directory.

I've attempted multiple regexes to try and give the `location` for these files a higher priority in nginx, but they seemed to have no effect.

How should this config file be changed in order to allow these kind of files, but still return a 403 on all other files inside those directories?

EDIT: the file URL's look like `https://example.com/app/js/something.min.js?v=1921` perhaps it doesn't work because of the `?v=1921` ?

Comment: The querystring won't be matched by `location` block. Is your nginx server behind of some kinds of CDNs? It may be caused by caches on those CDN servers. Try change the URL to https://example.com/app/js/something.min.js?v=1922 to bypass the cache.

Comment: I'm using cloudflare, but I've put myself in development mode and made sure to clear the cache. I know for a fact though that the url is like that because of pagekit itself

Comment: The cache is stored serverside by Cloudflare so only browser development mode won't work actually. Perhaps you can just change the version number from "1921" to any other string and see if it will work, after you moved the last `location` to the top.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not something I can change. I'm trying to find / write a regex that ignores the query string, but so far no luck

Comment: Actually you can. Just copy the URL and change the parameter, then browse the JS file directly to see if still a 403 returned.

Comment: oh, yeah you're right. forgot about that. Unfortunately that too returns a 403

Comment: How about add a "`break;`" after the last `add_header` line? Not sure but it might be the problem. (You still need to adjust the list order).

Comment: Doesn't seem to help either :/ (It's already at the top)

Comment: Can you update the question to the new configuration you modified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129484/discussion-between-xorinzor-and-philip-tzou).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [nginx's document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> nginx checks locations given by regular expression in the order listed in the configuration file

So first you need to move your last `location` to the top.

Then the regular expression that tries to match static files is also incorrect. The dollar sign "`$`" should match the end of path but it was escaped by a prior backslash "`\`" (so it actually matches a character "$"). Remove the backslash will fix your issue:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ttf|woff)$ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but didn't help either, so I reverted that change.
EDIT: Check the updated question, perhaps that might explain the problem?

Comment: Interesting... I have similar rule in my nginx configuration and it works well. Have you reloaded nginx after you changed its config?

Comment: Yes, I did (Check the edit in the question, perhaps that explains?)